# Uncaught (in promise) Error: QWeb2: Template 'Dialog' not found

Tags: templates, dialog, odoo-13

When I'm trying to run Odoo apps on Odoo 13, then Odoo UI is not working correctly and I'm facing the following error in the browser console.
**Uncaught (in promise) Error: QWeb2: Template 'Dialog' not found**
snapshot is attached below:
[Uncaught (in promise) Error: QWeb2: Template 'Dialog' not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVvn0.png)

Please helpout, how to resolve this error.